# How to import only the minimum value with importXML from a group of values (class is product price)?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import prices from a category page with importxml (=IMPORTXML("https://www.elchkids.de/54-spielboegen-spielmatten";"//div[@itemprop='offers']/span[1]") or =IMPORTXML("https://www.elchkids.de/54-spielboegen-spielmatten";"//*[contains(@class,'price product-price')]")), which works, but then I get a column full of prices.

Instead, I need only the lowest price. On the webpage, they don't display it, so I can't pull it. Is there a way to filter this lowest price out while pulling all the prices? Something like =MIN(IMPORTXML(....))? Unfortunately this MIN approach didn't work out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it does work with MIN :)